# .env/user_vars Environment Variables are returning NULL

Tags: php, nginx, openshift, laravel-5

I am trying to setup Laravel 5.2 on Openshift using 
https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-php
https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-nginx

I am able to set the user variables like APP_DEBUG using action_hooks, but these environment variables are returning NULL in Laravel files. Please suggest a way to solve this problem! What am I missing that is not reading the variables in .env/user_vars/ directory.

**EDIT 1:**
Following is the code snippet of action_hooks/deploy

```
echo "Setting environment variables..." 1>&2
export APP_ENV="${APPLICATION_ENV:-production}"
if [[ "${APPLICATION_ENV:-}" != "development" ]]; then
  export APP_DEBUG=false
else
  export APP_DEBUG=true
fi

echo "App Debug Mode '$APP_DEBUG' '$APP_ENV'..." 1>&2

if [ "$(type -t set_env_var)" == "function" ]; then
  set_env_var 'APP_ENV' $APP_ENV $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
  set_env_var 'APP_DEBUG' $APP_DEBUG $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
fi

if [ ! -z "$OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS" ]; then
  export APP_URL="$OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS"
  echo "App URL '$APP_URL' '$OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'..." 1>&2
  if [ "$(type -t set_env_var)" == "function" ]; then
    set_env_var 'APP_URL' $APP_URL $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
  fi
fi

if [ ! -z "$OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN" ]; then
  export APP_KEY=davjhdfgdhayufgahgajgfdshadjaj
  echo "App KEY '$APP_KEY' '$OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN'..." 1>&2
  if [ "$(type -t set_env_var)" == "function" ]; then
    set_env_var 'APP_KEY' $APP_KEY $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
  fi
fi

echo "App Debug Mode '$APP_DEBUG' '$APP_ENV'..." 1>&2
echo "App KEY '$APP_KEY' '$OPENSHIFT_SECRET_TOKEN'..." 1>&2

Followed by the rest of code...
```

The output for this while deploying gives me

```
remote: Setting environment variables...
remote: App Debug Mode 'true' 'development'...
remote: App URL 'laravel-narsariamanu.rhcloud.com' 'laravel-narsariamanu.rhcloud.com'...
remote: App KEY 'davjhdfgdhayufgahgajgfdshadjaj' 'Ifm2BJ_o9pvLMyEykfwApI5FRLsZ5BZyGI54m2Lqu46XLLtx4aOWjFKYGfTOL3hhkRvm6dSLFmSHBP5xTKgAdtChXYXr6HEgq92qco4dC4fE-CkQR-82RV7UYE0N7_nq'...
remote: App Debug Mode 'true' 'development'...
remote: App KEY 'davjhdfgdhayufgahgajgfdshadjaj' 'Ifm2BJ_o9pvLMyEykfwApI5FRLsZ5BZyGI54m2Lqu46XLLtx4aOWjFKYGfTOL3hhkRvm6dSLFmSHBP5xTKgAdtChXYXr6HEgq92qco4dC4fE-CkQR-82RV7UYE0N7_nq'...
remote: 
remote: Database driver set to 'mysql'...
remote: Database set to '127.5.76.2' 'mysql' 'laravel' 'admin4QlGeTU' '7eTw_XGG4dSx'...
remote: OPENSHIFT Database set to '127.5.76.2' 'mysql' 'laravel' 'admin4QlGeTU' '7eTw_XGG4dSx'...
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Migrating storage and log directories...
remote: 
remote: 
remote: Running 'php artisan migrate --force'...
remote: 
remote: Nothing to migrate.
remote: Checking configuration
remote: - php-fpm.ini: No change
remote: - php-fpm.conf: No change
remote: - php.ini: No change
remote: PHP-FPM already running
remote: Nginx instance is started
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

In config/app.php in Laravel :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
| to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
| will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
|
*/

'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

This env('APP_KEY') returns NULL, though while deploying it is set.

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a minimal (code) example to reproduce your issue so that others can help. Best regards.

Comment: @YakovL Have update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes when you changed in your .env file it does not take correct values from that, the problem is due to some configuration cache.Try running following commands, hope will work

```
php artisan config:cache   //cached all files under config directory
php artisan config:clear   //repopulate all the env variable and clear config cache
php artisan cache:clear    //flush all the cached content (route, view, config cache)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little late but here is the answer. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8191

As a summary it is suggested to set the value in your config file(I reference them to my env file). then you can call from config files. 
`\Config::get('app.env')` instead of `env('APP_ENV')` and in my app.php file in config folder I set:
`'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`

`php artisan config:cache` did not solve my problem.

I hope it help you guys. 
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file check your variables_order. IF it reads "GPCS" try adding E to the beginning and restart your server, then see what happens.

If any of the lines in .env have spaces and aren't enclosed in " then it'll fail.

**Some things to try**

- Check the permissions for your .env file. Try setting it to 777 as a
  test, to see what will happen. (if that works, don't keep it at 777)
- Run php artisan config:cache, and php artisan config:clear command.
- restart your app server.